# Rest API to request a build passing parameters TFS 2013

Tags: api, rest, visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

I need to queue a build on TFS 2013 passing MSBuild arguments. I am currently making the below mentioned REST API call. This does not allow me to pass any other arguments other than Build definition id, reason and priority.

https://{account}.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/{project}/_apis/build/requests?api-version={version}

I need to pass MSBUild argument like targetName for every build I queue. I need to achieve this using REST API and can not use TFS SDK . I have
looked all the APIS in the below link
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview

Could someone please suggest ways to achieve this?

Comment: TFSBuild command doesn't help?

Comment: I need to queue a build using a java program. I should be able to read the msbuildarguments of a build definition. Display default values if any and then allow the user to provide values for msbuildargs and then queue build with the new values.